# How do I manage the activation of vim abbreviation?

Tags: neovim, original-vim

I defined an abbreviation in vim like this:

```
ab is Input()
```

I know it is not good to use `is` as the abbreviation of `Input()`; here it is just an example.

So every time when I type `is` followed by space, then `is` will be automatically changed to `Input()`.

Is it possible to disable the automatic trigger on space (other triggers include non-keyword characters, <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)? So I can use other keys such as `ctrl+]` to trigger the abbreviation if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, space will always trigger an abbreviation. At best you could analyse the context to prevent expansion within strings or comment for instance.

The closest you could have to abbreviations, but with other triggers would be to register the association into a dictionary, and then search in that dictionary to do the replacement.

Something like

```
" In autoload/myabbrev.vim
let s:global_assocs = get(s:, 'global_assocs', {})
let s:buffer_assocs = get(s:, 'buffer_assocs', {})

function! myabbrev#register(args) abort
  let buffer = 0
  let expr   = 0
  let args = a:args
  while 1
    let [all, w, tail; _] = matchlist(args, '^\s*\(<buffer>\|<expr>\)\=\s*\(.*\)')
    " echomsg "##".w."##  ##".tail."##"
    if     w == '<buffer>' | let buffer = 1
    elseif w == '<expr>'   | let expr   = 1
    else
      " TODO: handle "foo\ bar"
      let [all, lhs, rhs; _] = matchlist(args, '\v\s*(\S+)\s+(.*)')
      " echomsg "#LHS:#".lhs."##  #RHS:#".rhs."##"
      break
    endif
    let args = tail
  endwhile

  if buffer
    let bid = bufnr('%')
    if !has_key(s:buffer_assocs, bid)
      let s:buffer_assocs[bid] = {}
    endif
    let assocs = s:buffer_assocs[bid]
  else
    let assocs = s:global_assocs
  endif
  let assocs[lhs] = {'rhs': rhs, 'expr': expr}
endfunction

function! myabbrev#expand() abort
  let lead_len = col('.')-1
  let lead = getline('.')[:lead_len]
  " strlen is perfect here, even with multi-bytes chars, given the
  " previous len counted in bytes.
  let bid = bufnr('%')
  if has_key(s:buffer_assocs, bid)
    let assocs = s:buffer_assocs[bid]
    let matches = filter(keys(assocs), {_,k -> lead[lead_len-strlen(k) :] == k})
  endif
  if empty(get(l:, 'matches', []))
    let assocs = s:global_assocs
    let matches = filter(keys(assocs), {_,k -> lead[lead_len-strlen(k) :] == k})
  endif
  if len(matches) > 1
    "TODO: analyse the best match, or ask user
  elseif empty(matches)
    " echomsg "No match found"
    return ''
  else
    " strlen is not compatible with multi-bytes characters
    " -^GU => redo
    let del = repeat("\<c-g>U\<bs>", strwidth(matches[0]))
    let assoc = assocs[matches[0]]
    " echomsg string(assoc)
    let rhs = assoc.rhs
    if assoc.expr
      let rhs = eval(rhs)
    endif
    return del . rhs
  endif
endfunction

"----------------------------------------------------------------------
" in plugin/myabbrev.vim
command! -nargs=1 MyAbbrev call myabbrev#register(<f-args>)

" I don't use <expr> in case more is required.
inoremap <silent> <Plug>(myabbrv-expand) <c-r>=myabbrev#expand()<cr>
if !hasmapto('<Plug>(myabbrv-expand)', 'i')
  imap <silent> <unique> µ <Plug>(myabbrv-expand)
endif
```

Note: this is somewhat a very simplified version of what is done with snippets except that registration is done completely differently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using vim abbreviations.  The closest you can come is to press CTRL-V before pressing the next key that would otherwise trigger the abbreviation.

If you wish to have this behaviour (expanding `is` to `Input()`) on pressing a key then I suspect you'd have to do it with completions.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, I think I will move to snippet instead.